# How can I use VB.NET to configure a DataAdapter to use Sql Server Stored Procedures for Select, Update, Insert and Delete commands?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, datagridview, sqldataadapter

I have created a test project that is simply to make a DataGridView work with Sql Server by using stored procedures. I take care of all the SQL Server machinations within an Employee class, and the datagridview activities on the form frmMain.

By nature, I am going to use some of the same columns in all four commands.

I want to define each parameter one time, then add it to all the commands that need it. Trouble is, I get the error "SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection". Somebody told me that I will have to name each parameter differently for each of the commands that use it. I can see how this would be so, but I am hoping that somebody out there knows how to make the one-column-one-parameter approach work.

```vb
Employee Class

Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Employees
    'Declarations
    Private dtEmployees As DataTable
    Private daEmployeer As SqlDataAdapter
    Const HotmixCn As String = "Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=USER;Password=password"
    Private Cn As SqlConnection

    'Properties
    Public Property EmployeeList As DataTable

        Get
            Return dtEmployees
        End Get
        Set(value As DataTable)
            dtEmployees = value

        End Set
    End Property


    'Methods
    Public Sub New()
        ' Try
        Cn = New SqlConnection(HotmixCn)
        daEmployeer = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim cmdSelectEmployees As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmdInsertEmployee As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmdUpdateEmployee As New SqlCommand
        Dim cmdDeleteEmployee As New SqlCommand
        'Configure the Select command (!! have to for SP)
        With cmdSelectEmployees
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "uspTestGetEmployees"
            .Connection = Cn

        End With

    --- Same thing for Insert, Update and Delete
        '
        '/// Add The Parameters To All Three Commands ///
        Dim parm As SqlParameter
        parm = New SqlParameter
        With parm
            .ParameterName = "@EmpNo"
            .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            .SourceColumn = "EmpNo"
        End With
        cmdInsertEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm)
        cmdUpdateEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm)
        'cmdDeleteEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm)
        '
----- Similar for remaining parameters            

        '
        'Include the individual commands in the dataadapter
        daEmployeer.SelectCommand = cmdSelectEmployees
        daEmployeer.UpdateCommand = cmdUpdateEmployee
        daEmployeer.InsertCommand = cmdInsertEmployee
        daEmployeer.DeleteCommand = cmdDeleteEmployee
        '/// Fill the Datatable
        dtEmployees = New DataTable

        Cn.Open()
        daEmployeer.Fill(dtEmployees)
        Cn.Close()


        'Catch ex As Exception
        'MsgBox(ex.Message)

        'End Try

    End Sub
    'Events

End Class
```

This is the little code that goes with the DataGridView:

```
Imports DataLayer

Public Class frmMain
    Dim emp As New Employees

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        dgvEmployees.DataSource = emp.EmployeeList

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Too much code... try to strip it down to a very basic example to get more interest in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to add the same parameter to two different parameter collection in two different SqlCommand. This is not possible as you can see from the error message.

A possible workaround is to create a duplicate of the original command and add this duplicate to the different command. This is a tedious work, so it is better to create an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx) that do the dirty work for you

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module SqlClientExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Function Duplicate(ByVal src As SqlParameter) As SqlParameter
        Dim copy = New SqlParameter(src.ParameterName,src.SqlDbType, src.Size, src.Direction,
                                      src.IsNullable, src.Precision, src.Scale, src.SourceColumn,
                                      src.SourceVersion, src.Value)

        Return copy; 
    End Function 

End Module
```

And now you could write something like this

```
Dim parm As SqlParameter
parm = New SqlParameter
With parm
    .ParameterName = "@EmpNo"
    .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
    .Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    .SourceColumn = "EmpNo"
End With
cmdInsertEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm)
cmdUpdateEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm.Duplicate())
cmdDeleteEmployee.Parameters.Add(parm.Duplicate())
```

I have also noticed that the SqlParameter implements the interface ICloneable. So, at first sight it seems that you could write something like this

```
Dim b = new SqlCommand()
Dim p = new SqlParameter()
p.ParameterName = "@Test"
b.Parameters.Add(p)

Dim b1 = new SqlCommand()
Dim p1 = CType(CType(p, ICloneable),SqlParameter)
b1.Parameters.Add(p1)
```

but this falls back to the original error *"SqlParameter is already contained by another SqlParameterCollection"* (and, even if it worked, I would prefer the Extension Method for its clarity)

Comment: That looks like a very elegant way to do what I want to do - which is important because I am going to have to do same-but-different situations many times. I don't exactly understand where to put the extension, but I will find that out. Thanks and if somebody doesn't come up with an even better way by the time I learn about it, I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: The link above about Extension Methods in vb.net should explain a lot. And, sure, wait all the time you like, that's how SO works

Comment: This is a really cool way to do this task, that is going to save lots of headache for me and for others. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to define each parameter one time, then add it to all the commands that need it.

Unfortunately, that's just not allowed. You'll have to bite the bullet and redefine the parameter for the select, update, and delete commands.